# Generate HTML Test Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest

How can we generate html test report using pytest for a test suite having multiple test cases?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
suite = unittest.TestSuite((unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(A.A),
                                    unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(B.B),
                                    ))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I am using following command to run and generate html test report - pytest -v Script.py --html=Script.html
no report is generated.

Comment: Your test script name should have the keyword test in it Eg: test_script or script_test. Then try running pytest -v test_script.py --html=report.html --self-contained-html

Comment: @akvenk I want a html report in which all my testcases are displayed.

Comment: did you try the above line? Also why do you want to see testcases in the html report?

Comment: @akvenk Yes, it is generating a single report.
Testcases in html report would signify exactly which test case failed in case of failure, whereas this would explain the complete failure of script.